# Linux remove files without giving error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

I have this running as cron job

```
/usr/bin/find /backups/* -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But it gives me this error on email

```
/usr/bin/find: `/backups/Jun-20-2014': No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to ignore that error without redirecting the error output

Comment: I don't think this command or any of the answers will do what you expect. `mtime` on directories is the time files got moved to/from the directory, it does not change when a file gets updated. So this will try files that were either modified more than five days ago or files that happen to be in directories where nothing has been moved in/out of for five days regardless of how long ago they were modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xargs` like this:

```
find /backups/ -mtime +5 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

`-0` is there to handle filenames with spaces properly. Note that this will work much faster than `find -exec` because it will try to put many files into single `rm` invocation.

Comment: Confused how optimizing run time is supposed to fix the 'error'.

Comment: I think error introduced by `rm -rf` which removes some directory, and as find continues search, it is confused by absence of this directory by this time. My solution splits enumeration by `find` from removal by `xargs rm`.

Comment: Didn't realize `rm -f non_existant_file` wouldn't throw stderr. Feels roundabout, but I guess +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is an **ugly** workaround, but it worked for me on several cases…

You can store the command's output into a var by redirecting the output to `stdout`, like this:

```
result=$( <your find command here> 2>&1 )
```

Since `find` doesn't output anything on success, any error is sent to `stderr` and the output stored into `result` is only what's sent to `stdout`, we redirect `stderr` to `stdout` to capture the error on `$result`, then you can check wether `$result` is empty (success) or not (there was an error). So you can make your code to send you the mail accordingly:

```
if [ -z "$result" ]; then
    # If $result is empty, find was successful
else
    # The result is not empty because there was
    # an error, send a mail to notify.
fi
```

This of course ignores the premise of *not redirecting the output*, but since I don't know *why* you don't want to redirect it, this *may* be a solution.

Comment: That's why I said it was an _ugly_ ***workaround***…

Comment: Maybe if you just redirected `stderr` to `/dev/null`, but you're redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` and then saying `the output stored into result is only what's sent to stdout`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's because `find` doesn't output anything on success, but throws an error into `stderr` on failure, and we want to know if there was an error or not (redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null` won't help at all) so we redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so `result` ends up being empty on success and not empty on failure, and you can just check wether `result` is empty (success) or not (failure). Or use mvp's answer.

Comment: `find` could still remove everything as expected, despite throwing the `stderr`. But I definitely misinterpreted what you wrote +1, though in the context of the question `2>/dev/null` would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the file is there when the shell expands `*` but then no more there when `find` processes it.

You could try with:

```
/usr/bin/find /backups/ -depth 1 -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This will process all the files in `/backups/` and with `-depth 1` excluding the starting directory itself.

Comment: You're thinking of `-mindepth 1`. And `/backups/` rather than `/backups/*` is probably the better syntax, but more so to avoid `ARG_MAX`

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-issue. `find` pre-processes parts of the tree, and when it tries to reach already deleted files it throws stderr.

You can just ignore the errors, `-prune` the directory, or traverse in `DFS` fassion, i.e. one of the following

```
/usr/bin/find /backups/ -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} + 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/find /backups/ -mtime +5 -prune -exec rm -rf {} +
/usr/bin/find /backups/ -depth -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

*+ can used use for commands that take multiple arguments, so you don't need to run more rm's than required*

The **real issue** is with your use of `mtime`. What I'm assuming you want to do is delete files that were not modified within the last five days. Then you should explicitly delete only files, i.e. one of the following

```
/usr/bin/find /backups/ -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm -f {} +
/usr/bin/find /backups/ -type f -mtime +5 -delete
```

And afterwords you can include a second find command to delete empty directories, i.e. one of the following

```
/usr/bin/find /backups/ -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
/usr/bin/find /backups/ -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -exec rm -rf {} +
```

The problem with deleting directories based on mtime, is mtime will change only when files get moved to/from the directory. But it can still have files that got modified within the last five days, despite having a modification time that's older.